# Join clojure sets on multiple keys

Tags: join, clojure

Is there a way to join clojure sets on multiple keys ?
For exemple, I have set1 and set2 . I want to join the based on keys :a and :b

`(def set1 #{ {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} {:a 3 :b 4 :c 5} })
  (def set2 #{ {:a 1 :b 2 :d 4} {:a 3 :b 4 :d 6} {:a 7 :b 7} {:a 1 :b 2 :c 4}})`

desired output is

`#{{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4}  {:a 1 :b 2 :c 4} {:a 3 :b 4 :c 5 :d 6} }`

Answer (score 5):

One way to do so is to use clojure.set/join :

`(clojure.set/join set1 set2 {:a :a :b :b})`

It joins set1 and set2 based on the map `{:a :a :b :b}` which means it compares the value of `:a` in the firs map to the value of `:a` on the second map and the value of `:b` in the firs map to the value of `:b` on the second map

Answer (score 0):

Seems like simple

```clj
cljs.user=> (clojure.set/join set1 set2)
#{{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3, :d 4}
  {:a 3, :b 4, :c 5, :d 6}
  {:a 1, :b 2, :c 4}}
```

did the same.

Comment: clojure.set/join without providing the keys to join on, joins on all the common keys, in my case I want it to join only on keys :a and :b